# What properties of later elements are predicted by scientists?

Tags: periodic-table

Though scientists have predicted up to element 172 (unseptbium) what properties do they predict any elements later on the extended periodic table may have?

Comment: Later then 172?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/the-last-elements-atomic-number

Answer (score 1):

Though elements past 92 are quite unstable, so that chemical properties are difficult to determine, heavier elements behave more like metals, since the outer electrons are well shielded from the attraction of the positive nucleus and will therefore be easily lost.

Another predictable property is specific heat, which decreases with increased atomic mass.