# If an atom had 200 protons, how much neutrons would it need to have to be most likely stable and why?

Tags: atoms

I know there is a specific proton/neutron ratio but i'm unaware if it applies to atoms with 86 protons and beyond.

Comment: Such extrapolation is a moot point as nobody would be able to synthetise it. If magically succeeded, It would have t1/2 like 10^-23 s, decaying probably to 3 fractions.

Comment: BTW, it would fit better to Physics SE.

Comment: Theoretical physics states that no atom can have more than $137$ protons.

Comment: Related [the-last-elements-atomic-number](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/the-last-elements-atomic-number)

Comment: Uh ... [$10^{57}$?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star)